# Laravel 5.6 How to take duplicated datas from column

Tags: mysql, laravel

And that i want to print each `topic_id`'s count

**show.blade.php**

```
@foreach($questions as $question)
{{ $question->topic_id }}
@endforeach
```

**ExamsController@index**

```
$topics = Topic::all();
return view('exams.show', compact('topics','questions'));
```

Just want to take duplicated datas count and print.

```
| id | topic_id |
| ---|:--------:|
| 1  |     4    |
| 2  |     9    |
| 3  |     5    |
| 4  |     5    |
| 5  |     2    |
| 6  |     4    |
| 7  |     5    |
```

that i wanted result is count of each topic_id duplicates. its like

```
| id | topic_id |
| ---|:--------:|
| 1  |     4    |
| 6  |     4    |
```

**2**

```
| id | topic_id |
| ---|:--------:|
| 3  |     5    |
| 4  |     5    |
| 7  |     5    |
```

count = 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could make use of [`groupBy`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#ordering-grouping-limit-and-offset)

```
$duplicates = Topic::selectRaw("count('id') as total, topic_id")
                   ->groupBy('topic_id')
                   ->get();

// pass the duplicates along with other variables to the view
return view('exams.show', compact('topics','questions', 'duplicates'));
```

and in your view you could do

```
@foreach ($duplicates as $duplicate)
{{ $duplicate->topic_id }} - {{ $duplicate->total }}
@endforeach
```

Comment: Sir. How do i print each `topic_id` like `topic_id 4 = 2` `topic_id 5 = 3`.

Comment: Thank you sir. It works fine as well. Now i trying to understand your code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use collection feature on laravel to group data by topic_id

```
$topic = Topic::all();
$topicArray = $topic->groupBy('topic_id')->toArray();
```

in your view you can simply use $topicArray to display your data & count its duplicate

```
@foreach ($topicArray as $key => $value)
  @foreach ($value as $key2 => $value2)
    | {{ $value2['id'] }} | {{ $value2['topic_id'] }} |<br>
  @endforeach
  count {{ count($value) }}<br><br>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what duplicated datas you mean, but I believe you are looking for a distinct.

> The distinct method allows you to force the query to return distinct
>   results
>   https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queries#selects

```
$topics = Topic::distinct()->get();
```